# Plotting Complex I/Q Data

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm currently using Redhawk to to decode an incoming VITA49 packet stream. The data in this stream is interleaved I/Q data, encoded as IEEE-754 floats. This is working correctly, except when plotting the `dataFloat_out` port, which seems to plot the data as real-only, even when set to "Real and Imaginary". For test purposes, I've set the I data to be always 0.9, and the Q data to be always 0.1. Capturing this using `Data List` and displaying it as Complex shows the data is arriving and being decoded correctly, just not displayed as it should be.

I've verified (using wireshark) that the context packets that are being sent are correct with respect to how it should be interpreted (complex cartesian).

Is there anything I am missing / need to do to plot I/Q data correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In REDHAWK the bulkio data stream will have an accompanying SRI push which contains signal related information. The SRI push will have a "mode" attribute that is either set to 0 (real) or 1 (complex). You can right click on the dataFloat_out port and select view SRI and confirm what the SRI is set to, if the SRI's mode is set to real then the plot will respect that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The mode is set to [0] scalar - is there any way to change this?

Comment: The issue could either be in the VITA stream, or the component that's ingesting the VITA. If you know for sure the content is complex you can create another component that will flip the mode flag to 1 and do your plotting after that. There are lots of plotting options as well if you hit "m" when the plot window has focus although I'm unsure if any of those will change how the data is interpreted.